# Links sometimes do not work cause of htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When I try to open   :

`http://custom.dev/pages/tpl/front/img/main.jpg`   works

but when I try to open same file from another directory :

```
http://custom.dev/uploads/home-banners/main.jpg
```

It do not works , it redirect me to home page and in apache logs I see :

```
"GET /uploads/home-banners/main.jpg HTTP/1.1" 302 454 "http://custom.dev/"
```

If I delete .htaccess both links open , but site needs htaccess to work well

I use the next .htaccess , what could be the problem?

```
RewriteEngine On 

#FileETag none

##########################################################################
#### ADMIN
##########################################################################

# 8 vars
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6&var6=$7&var7=$8&var8=$9 [L]
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6&var6=$7&var7=$8&var8=$9 [L]
# 7 vars
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6&var6=$7&var7=$8 [L]
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6&var6=$7&var7=$8 [L]
# 6 vars
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6&var6=$7 [L]
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6&var6=$7 [L]
# 5 vars
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6 [L]
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6 [L]
# 4 vars
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5 [L]
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5 [L]
# 3 vars
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4 [L]
# 2 var
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)/ pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/(.*)  pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3 [L]
# 1 var
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)/ pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule wf-admin/(.*)  pages/wfagate.php?file=$1&var1=$2 [L]
# 0 var
RewriteRule wf-admin/ pages/wfagate.php?file=$1 [L]


##########################################################################
#### FORONT END
##########################################################################

# 6 vars
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6&var6=$7 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6&var6=$7 [L]
# 5 vars
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5&var5=$6 [L]
# 4 vars
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4&var4=$5 [L]
# 3 vars
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)  /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4 [L]
# 2 var
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)  /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3 [L]
# 1 var
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)  /index.php?file=$1&var1=$2 [L]
# 0 var
RewriteRule (.*)/ /index.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteRule scripts.js /engine/include/functions/loadFiles.php
RewriteRule styles.css /engine/include/functions/loadFiles.php?what=css
```

Comment: You are rewriting everything to index.php, treating path segments with slashes in between as different numbers of "variables." Usually rewriting such as this is preceded by conditions excluding requests for physically existing files or folders, but in your code there's nothing to be seen of that. So, how those two different image URLs are processed further totally depends on your index.php

Comment: yes , what i'm searching for is for it to do not rewite for png jpg ending files , but i'm not a pro of htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple rules that might be affecting existing files or directories.

**Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line to skip all files and directories:**

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```